# I forgot my Apple ID and my email password

Tags: ipad

My mother ask someone to make an Apple ID for her now she has forgotten her Apple ID and because someone else made it for her she doesn't know anything about his email and security questions.

Now her iPad needs to be updated but is locked to that Apple ID and we don't know how we can fix it.

Can someone please help us .

How I can change Apple ID without knowing Apple ID and email and security questions.

Comment: Are you able to unlock the iPad? If yes, what email-ID can you see under `Settings app → 1st item (Apple ID, iCloud, iTunes & App Store)`?

Comment: **Note**: Please don't post the actual Apple ID in response to @NimeshNeema

Comment: Apple Store will allow you to prove ownership of the iPad through other means, and will allow you to update or change the Apple ID associated with it. If the Apple ID was not associated to an email address accessed by your mother, then it's not really her Apple ID, So my suggestion is to make an appointment at  an Apple Store. You can always request support for an iPad at support.apple.com, but proving ownership could be more challenging online.